# Yii: Dynamically change model relation type with model()->with()

Tags: php, model, yii, relationship

I have `GoodsCats` model with next relations:

```
public function relations(){
  return array(
    'GoodsCatsContent' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'GoodsCatsContent', 'parent_id'),
  );
}
```

And now I want to find all `GoodsCats` elements but with one child element (with specific `language_id`):

```
$cats = GoodsCats::model()->with(
  array(
    'GoodsCatsContent'=>array(
      'on'=>'languages_id = 1'
    )
  )
)->findAll();
```

And recive an array where each elemt is like `GoodsCats.id=>GoodsCatsContent.name`:

```
CHtml::listData(cats, 'id', 'name')
```

But for now I'm getting an error `GoodsCats.name not defined`.
When I set `GoodsCats` relations as [self::HAS_ONE](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#relations-detail) all works good but I can't change it for whole project.
Is it posible somehow set [model()->with()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#with-detail) to use not defined relation type but a specific one?

**UPD** my models rules:

`GoodsCatsContent`:

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('parent_id', 'required'),
        array('active', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        array('parent_id', 'length', 'max'=>10),
        array('name, seo_title, seo_keywords, seo_description', 'length', 'max'=>255),
        array('short_content, content', 'safe'),
        array('id, parent_id, active, name, short_content, content, seo_title, seo_keywords, seo_description', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}
```

`GoodsCats`:

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('active, prior', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        array('photo', 'length', 'max'=>255),
        array('id, photo, active, prior', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}
```

Comment: What do your models look like?

Comment: @Jon Did you mean each model `rules()` or `search()`?

Comment: Your final requirement is an array of type: `GoodsCats.id=>GoodsCatsContent.name` ?

Comment: ok, so why don't you just loop through `$cats` and make the array yourself instead of relying on `listData`? if you are fine with that, this becomes quite easy, would you like an example?

Comment: @bool.dev I thought it is not good practice to do it like this. But for now I think it better than nothing.

Comment: Ok, so if you set language_id, you get only one name, i.e only one related GoodCatsContent record?

Comment: Yes but $cats anyway became array of objects (it is just a object if GoodsCats relation set as `self::HAS_ONE`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't dynamically change the relation type.

But, since you are sure that using `language_id = 1` gives you only one related `GoodsCatsContent` record, you can do this instead of using `listData()` :

```php
$myList=array();
foreach ($cats as $acat){
    $myList[$acat->id]=isset($acat->GoodsCatsContent[0]->name)? $acat->GoodsCatsContent[0]->name :''; 
    // you need isset incase some of the GoodsCats don't have a related GoodsCatsContent
}
// you can now use $myList as you would have used the array returned by listData()
```

Because this is a HAS_MANY relation, each `GoodsCats` will have x number of related GoodsCatsContent records, and therefore the relation will return an `array` always, even if there is only 1 related record, and an empty array if there is no related record. So when there is 1 related record, the `relationName[0]` will return that record.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$cats = GoodsCats::model()->with(
  array(
    'GoodsCatsContent'=>array(
      'condition'=>'languages_id = 1'
    )
  )
)->findAll();
```

or

```
$cats = GoodsCats::model()->with('GoodsCatsContent')->findAll('languages_id = 1');
```

Comment: No luck. `CHtml::listData($cats, 'id', 'GoodsCatsContent.name')` returns array with `GoodsCats` id's but with empty `GoodsCatsContent` names:  `Array ( [2] => [3] => [4] => ... )`